# Layout is disintegrated in Windows 7 but looks fine on Windows XP

Tags: java, jvm

I strange problem with Java, my app looks fine on windows XP but it lloks strange on Windows 7 ( layout is just disintegrated ). Did anybody have same problem ? TextFields are different size.

```
GroupLayout gl_panel = new GroupLayout(this);
        gl_panel.setHorizontalGroup(
                gl_panel.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(gl_panel.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addGroup(gl_panel.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(lblPulseFrequency, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 86, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(lblChannelDelay_4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 86, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(lblChannelDelay, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 86, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(lblChannelDelay_1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 86, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(lblChannelDelay_2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 86, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(lblChannelDelay_3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 86, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(lblBlankingTime, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 78, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(gl_panel.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addComponent(pulseFreqTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, 0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(blankingTimeTextField, 0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(textField_9)
                        .addComponent(textField_8)
                        .addComponent(textField_7)
                        .addComponent(textField_6)
                        .addComponent(textField_5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 85, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(gl_panel.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(gl_panel.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGroup(gl_panel.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(lblus_3)
                                .addComponent(lblus_2)
                                .addComponent(lblus_1)
                                .addComponent(lblus)
                                .addComponent(lblus_4))
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addGroup(gl_panel.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(lblChannelDelay_5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 84, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(lblChannelDelay_6)
                                .addComponent(lblChannelDelay_7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 84, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(lblChannelDelay_8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 84, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(lblChannelDelay_9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 84, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addGroup(gl_panel.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                .addComponent(textField_14)
                                .addComponent(textField_13)
                                .addComponent(textField_12)
                                .addComponent(textField_11)
                                .addComponent(textField_10, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 86, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addGroup(gl_panel.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addGroup(gl_panel.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                                    .addComponent(lblus_6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                    .addComponent(lblus_5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                    .addComponent(lblus_7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addComponent(lblus_8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING))
                                .addComponent(lblus_9))
                            .addGap(230, 230, 230))
                        .addGroup(gl_panel.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(lblkhz)
                            .addContainerGap())))
            );
            gl_panel.setVerticalGroup(
                gl_panel.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(gl_panel.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(gl_panel.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(gl_panel.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(117, 117, 117)
                            .addGroup(gl_panel.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(lblChannelDelay)
                                .addComponent(textField_5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(lblus)
                                .addComponent(lblChannelDelay_5)
                                .addComponent(textField_10, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(lblus_5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 17, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addGroup(gl_panel.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(lblChannelDelay_1)
                                .addComponent(textField_6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(lblus_1)
                                .addComponent(lblChannelDelay_6)
                                .addComponent(textField_11, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(lblus_6))
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addGroup(gl_panel.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(lblChannelDelay_2)
                                .addComponent(textField_7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(lblus_2)
                                .addComponent(lblChannelDelay_7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 17, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(textField_12, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 20, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(lblus_7))
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addGroup(gl_panel.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(lblChannelDelay_3)
                                .addComponent(textField_8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(lblus_3)
                                .addComponent(lblChannelDelay_8)
                                .addComponent(textField_13, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(lblus_8))
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addGroup(gl_panel.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addGroup(gl_panel.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                    .addComponent(lblChannelDelay_4)
                                    .addComponent(textField_9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                .addGroup(gl_panel.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                    .addComponent(lblus_4)
                                    .addComponent(lblChannelDelay_9)
                                    .addComponent(textField_14, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addComponent(lblus_9))))
                        .addGroup(gl_panel.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(42, 42, 42)
                            .addGroup(gl_panel.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(lblPulseFrequency)
                                .addComponent(pulseFreqTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(lblkhz))
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addGroup(gl_panel.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(lblBlankingTime)
                                .addComponent(blankingTimeTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
                    .addContainerGap(35, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            );
```

Comment: Add a screenshot!

Comment: Add some code too so we can see what layout manager, componenets etc you are using.

Comment: And tell some more about your problem. What layout are you using, what is the minimum set of components that present this problem etc..

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).  Adding a link to screen shots of working & broken GUIs would also be helpful (though that might also be achieved using ASCII Art).

Comment: We definitely need screenshots to be able to help, if possible two would be perfect: one on XP, one on W7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with different screen resolutions? Even if both machines have similar resolution, XP and 7 draw their margins, title bars etc. differently, which will affect the effective frame dimensions and so the Java layout can behave differently depending on the OS only. It's possible that the layout will explode completely if you actually change the screen resolution.

Your code looks like it's generated by some GUI builder such as NetBeans Matisse. I'm sorry to say, but they're simply bad. They give you [WYSIWYG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) impression, but they just aren't WYSIWYG. Consider coding the GUI by hand, using some good layout manager such as [MIGLayout](http://miglayout.com/).